# how to write the following mysql query in hive?

Tags: hive

MySQL query:

```
select * from user_balance_table  a where report_date < 20130901 and a.user_id not in (select user_id from user_balance_table  a where report_date <20130801);
```

How can i write the same query in hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.*
from
  (select * from user_balance_table
  where report_date < 20130901
  ) a           
  left outer join
  (select user_id 
  from user_balance_table  
  where report_date <20130801
  group by user_id
  ) b
on a.user_id=b.user_id and b.user_id is null;
```